# Wrapping div around circular background element

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

I have a text area within a background image that is partially obscured by a circular object.

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHaDq.png

I'd like some help wrapping text around that circular element, but also keeping the text within the blue area.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what have you tried so far? have you got any example code? This may help http://www.csstextwrap.com/examples.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Float a div for each overlapping row of text

The simplest option is to use @Vector's suggestion and float several divs of different widths to the left. Each floated div should have the same `height` as the `line-height` of the text, and should be wide enough to match the overlapping part of the circle.

The text will then automatically wrap around the floated divs. Use trial and error to determine the best width for each floated div.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/3TFEx/3/).

And here's an [altered version](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/2k36A/1/) of the demo that illustrates more clearly how the divs are floated. This should work fine in all browsers.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <!-- As many floated elements as needed -->
    <div class="float1"></div>
    <div class="float2"></div>
    ...
    <p>Text goes here</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content div {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    height: 24px;
}
.content div.float1 { width: ...; }
.content div.float2 { width: ...; }
...
.content p {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The kind of wrap that you want can be done through jQuery.

This plugin: http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/ has worked for me.

Good luck!