# Wrapping text around a rounded div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need to make text flow around a rounded div. I know i can use shape-outside: circle();. But unfortunately it doesn't work in older browsers.
Does anyone know of another method to do this in css? It's for a wordpress website.

```css
.logo-eye {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 439px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  width: 439px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-eye"></div>
<h1>Visie</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus id orci porta lorem sagittis iaculis tincidunt at dui.</p>
```

Comment: You can't do that, unfortunately. DIV is a box, even if you make it look like a circle with rounded corners.

Comment: Hope this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001550/wrapping-div-around-circular-background-element

Comment: Thanks @dingo_d it's nice and round now!

Answer (score 2):

[shape-outside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside)

Note:- only [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside#Browser_compatibility) in chrome

```css
img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  shape-outside: margin-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="image" />
  <div>
    <h2>Shape-outside</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus
    et interdum adipiscing wisi. Aliquam erat ac ipsum. Integer aliquam purus. Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo vel bibendum sapien massa ac turpis faucibus orci luctus non, consectetuer lobortis quis, varius in, paragraph.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use shape-outside because of that reason.